# Canvas getImageData not working on Mobile Safari

Tags: ios, html, mobile, canvas, safari

I am trying to extract the pixels from a canvas on mobile safari (iOS 5.0) but I am getting a strange TypeError:

```
> var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
> ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

> ImageDataConstructor
    constructor: Object
    data: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
    height: 50
    width: 50
    __proto__: Object
```

Somehow this extremely trivial piece of code is not working on mobile safari (testing with Weinre) but it does run on desktop safari and chrome.... 
Can anyone help me? Why is the data object reporting a TypeError??

Thanks,

Rob

PS. I tried with an empty canvas, and one with actual content in it

Comment: How did you get the canvas object ? Can we see more code ?

Answer (score 1):

This documentation says that canvas.drawImage() is not available on iOS.

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/PuttingVideoonCanvas/PuttingVideoonCanvas.html

I'm assuming that it's symmetrical and canvas.getImageData() is disabled too 8(